# Error while creating build from cordova in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3.
Required by:android:unspecified
Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.2.3/gradle-1.2.3.pom'.
peer not authenticated
```